# Deploy large number of Content Files in MVC project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 to write a MVC4 Web application. This project depends on an hierarchical folder structure, which contains over 10000 files and 100 folders. This structure is currently put in the Content folder of the MVC application.

What I want to do is to deploy this structure of files and folders only once to the server, and after to deploy only changes to code. (basically a kind of Copy to Output Directory -> Copy if Newer applied recursively  What is the proper way to do this?

Thank you,

Comment: `10000 files and 100 folders.`? WTF? Did you consider using a CDN for your static resources? Also combining and minifying them could be beneficial. And if those are some user uploaded data, you might consider off-loading them to a separate node from your web application - like Amazon S3 for example. It's kind of designed for this purpose.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm using a someone else DLL which read from this structure and I can't change this. So, CDN is not an option.

Comment: OK, then all I can do is wish you best of luck with this.